# Python: pickling nested functions

Tags: python, function, nested, pickle

Using the example

```
def foo(a):
    def bar(b):
        return a+b
    return bar

d = {1:foo(1), 2:foo(2)}
```

It appears that pickle module will not work with a function not defined at the module scope, so pickling 'd' will not work. Is there another pickling mechanism available that I should consider?

Comment: @Maxim Khesin I fixed the error others pointed out because it seems pretty obvious what you meant. Please shout at me if my edit is wrong.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I'm afraid that you can't pickle nested functions.

The `pickle` module serializes functions by name. That is, if you have a function `myfunc` in a module `mymodule` it simply saves the name `mymodule.myfunc` and looks it up again when unserializing. (This is an important security and compatibility issue, as it guarantees that the unserializing code uses its own definition for the function, rather than the original definition which might be compromised or obsolete.)

Alas, `pickle` can't do that with nested functions, because there's no way to directly address them by name. Your `bar` function, for instance, can't be accessed from outside of `foo`.

If you need a serializable object that works like a function, you can instead make a class with a `__call__` method:

```
class foo(object):
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def __call__(self, b): # the function formerly known as "bar"
        return self.a + b
```

This works just like the nested functions in the question, and should pose no problem to `pickle`. Do be aware though, that you'll need to have the same class definition available when you unserialize a `foo` instance.

Comment: the really good advantage that comes with it, is that it forces you to structure your code

Answer (score 16):

You can pickle nested functions if you use `dill` instead of `pickle`.

```
>>> import dill
>>>    
>>> def foo(a):
...   def bar(b):
...     return a+b
...   return bar
... 
>>> d = {1:foo(1), 2:foo(2)}
>>> 
>>> _d = dill.dumps(d)
>>> d_ = dill.loads(_d)
>>> d_
{1: <function bar at 0x108cfe848>, 2: <function bar at 0x108cfe8c0>}
>>> d[1](0) + d[2](10)
13
>>>
```

Comment: Correct answer! Thanks a lot, Mike.

Comment: I tried pasting this exact code into my python script and I get

TypeError: cannot pickle 'sqlite3.Connection' object

Comment: @skrhee: I think something additional is going on with your environment.  See my comment on your post here: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/435

Answer (score 0):

according to Blckknght's answersing. if nested function is the only extrac serialized type and will use it as `decorator`, you can just add `functools.warps` at top of inner function defination to lead other interpret find the correct name:

```py
from functools import warps

def foo(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def bar(b):
        return func(b)
    return bar

@foo
def zzz(b):
    return b
```