# weird behavior of multiprocessing scipy optimization inside of a function

Tags: python, optimization, parallel-processing, scipy, multiprocessing

Here is a simple code that runs well. Even if the function minimize wraps the scipy.optimize.minimize it does not complain about pickling

```
import numpy as np
from scipy import optimize
from multiprocessing import Pool

def square(x):
    return np.sum(x**2+ 2*x)

def minimize(args):
    f,x = args
    res = optimize.minimize(f, x, method = 'L-BFGS-B')
    return res.x

x = np.random.rand(8,10)

args = [(square,x[i]) for i in range(8)]
p = Pool(8)
p.map(minimize,args)
```

However, if try the following it fails with the pickling error

`PicklingError: Can't pickle <type 'function'>: attribute lookup __builtin__.function failed`

```py
def run():
    def square(x):
        return np.sum(x**2+ 2*x)

    def minimize(args):
        f,x = args
        res = optimize.minimize(f, x, method = 'L-BFGS-B')
        return res.x

    x = np.random.rand(8,10)

    args = [(square,x[i]) for i in range(8)]
    p = Pool(8)
    p.map(minimize,args)

run()
```

I want to make a module to use scipy minimize in parallel with many population of initial guesses. However, as shown in the example, when I make it a module, it fails.

Comment: The `pickle` module can only pick top-level functions. In your second example, `square` is not a top-level function, so it fails to pickle it.

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019961/python-pickling-nested-functions).

Comment: Thank you @dano. But the same error occurs if I take square out of the box. I mean just before the definition of run(). Doesn't it make it top-level?

Comment: You'll have to to the same with `minimize`, since you're passing that to `map`, too. Sorry, should have noticed that to begin with.

Comment: Oh, great. Thank you @dano

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Python cannot pickle nested functions, and in your second example, you're trying to pass the nested `minimize` and `square` functions to your child process, which requires pickling.

If there's no reason that you must nest those two functions, moving them to the top-level of the module will fix the issue. You can also see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019961/python-pickling-nested-functions) for techniques to pickle nested functions.