# Using ray with scipy functions

Tags: python, scipy, ray

[Ray](https://github.com/robertnishihara/ray) allows for parallel processing and I am trying to use it with `scipy` module. I just setup  `ray` and I am not sure if the behavior is expected. But anyway here is the script and the output.

```
    import math
    import cmath as cm
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.integrate import dblquad
    import ray

    ray.init(num_cpus=6) # initializing ray here 
    #-----------------------------------------------------------

    # DEFINE FUNCTIONS (I am not sure if i should use decorator here)

    def wrap_real(r,  rho, phi):
        res = cm.cos(phi)*cm.exp(-1j*2*math.pi*cm.sqrt(rho**2 +\
                    r**2))/cm.sqrt(rho**2 + r**2)
        return res.real

    def wrap_imag(r,  rho, phi):
        res = cm.cos(phi)*cm.exp(-1j*2*math.pi*cm.sqrt(rho**2 + \
                    r**2))/cm.sqrt(rho**2 + r**2)
        return res.imag

    rMax = 5

    # Functions called by ray
    @ray.remote
    def I_real (value ):
        return dblquad(lambda rho, phi: wrap_real (value ,  rho, phi) \
                       , 0, rMax, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*math.pi)
    @ray.remote
    def I_imag (value ):
        return dblquad(lambda rho, phi: wrap_imag ( value,  rho, phi) ,\
                       0, rMax, lambda x: 0, lambda x: 2*math.pi)
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    #-----------------------------------------------------------
    # TEST INTEGRATION

    print("\n-----------COMPLEX INTEGRATION RESULT ----------")

    run1 = I_real.remote(6)
    run2 = I_imag.remote(6)

    run3 = I_real.remote(6)
    run4 = I_imag.remote(7)

    run5 = I_real.remote(8)
    run6 = I_imag.remote(10)

    resultp1=ray.get([run1, run2])
    resultp2=ray.get([run3, run4])
    resultp3=ray.get([run5, run6])

    print(resultp1)
    print(resultp2)
    print(resultp3)
```

---

**OUTPUT**

```
2019-06-01 19:07:55,609 INFO node.py:497 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2019-06-01_19-07-55_608930_25145/logs.
2019-06-01 19:07:55,713 INFO services.py:409 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:32983 to respond...
2019-06-01 19:07:55,846 INFO services.py:409 -- Waiting for redis server at 127.0.0.1:18737 to respond...
2019-06-01 19:07:55,847 INFO services.py:806 -- Starting Redis shard with 10.0 GB max memory.
2019-06-01 19:07:55,882 INFO node.py:511 -- Process STDOUT and STDERR is being redirected to /tmp/ray/session_2019-06-01_19-07-55_608930_25145/logs.
2019-06-01 19:07:55,883 WARNING services.py:1293 -- Warning: Capping object memory store to 20.0GB. To increase this further, specify `object_store_memory` when calling ray.init() or ray start.
2019-06-01 19:07:55,884 INFO services.py:1441 -- Starting the Plasma object store with 20.0 GB memory using /dev/shm.

-----------COMPLEX INTEGRATION RESULT ----------
2019-06-01 19:07:56,446 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,467 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,467 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,467 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,548 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,560 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,571 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,572 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,604 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,606 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,628 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,629 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 59, in <module>
    resultp1=ray.get([run1, run2])
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 2197, in get
    raise value
ray.exceptions.RayTaskError: ray_worker:ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real() (pid=25201, host=varsh)
TypeError: f() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given

>>> 2019-06-01 19:07:56,911     ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,911 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,932 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,933 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,934 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,945 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,967 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,968 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,979 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,979 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:56,990 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real' with function ID ca83a4149613ad1164353ce7183f9a21dd1da53f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.

2019-06-01 19:07:57,000 ERROR worker.py:1678 -- Failed to unpickle the remote function 'ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_imag' with function ID b09f533dace5def97fe6c388da2e8b0be6c7d06f. Traceback:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/function_manager.py", line 424, in fetch_and_register_remote_function
    function = pickle.loads(serialized_function)
  File "/home/ankit/Documents/confocal_vol_python/ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py", line 13, in <module>
    ray.init(num_cpus=6)
  File "/home/ankit/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ray/worker.py", line 1351, in init
    raise Exception("Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? "
Exception: Perhaps you called ray.init twice by accident? This error can be suppressed by passing in 'ignore_reinit_error=True' or by calling 'ray.shutdown()' prior to 'ray.init()'.
```

Any suggestions regarding the output.

Comment: Probably related to this question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39777299/weird-behavior-of-multiprocessing-scipy-optimization-inside-of-a-function?rq=1

But i do not know how to bypass the limitation.

Comment: code working, don't get any error related to ray.init

Comment: Oh, i see. I will check my installation.

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpachi  : If possible could you post the output received. (maybe use pastebin or something)

Comment: [(-0.11678688737646281, 1.7636954379590675e-09), (0.1479416501795927, 3.1158250007878863e-09)], [(-0.11678688737646281, 1.7636954379590675e-09), (0.147397575183974, 3.0855094109057124e-10)], [(-0.14107337021052904, 3.9931410135159824e-11), (0.09913984173910342, 1.4866783904780216e-12)]

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpachi : Thank you. :-)

Comment: @Zaraki Kenpachi : I was able to get it working after a new installation of ray and updating numpy on my system.

Comment: The code you posted works for me as well. However, based on the error, my guess is that what is happening is when the remote function `ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.I_real` (from the error message) is pickled and shipped to the worker processes, the worker processes try to unpickle it, and the process of unpickling it requires the module `ques_modpy_asked_SO_modifying2.py` to be imported, and that runs `ray.init()`, which shouldn't be run on the workers. If the issue occurs again, it should be fixable by moving the `ray.init()` into a `if __name__ == '__main__':` block.

Comment: @Robert Nishihara : Thank you. I was able to use my code after correct installation of Ray. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found that the problem was in building Ray from source and presumably it was not installed correctly.

An installation using `pip install -U ray` did it.

As mentioned in the comments by Robert, moving `ray.init()` inside `if __name__ == '__main__':` block allows for proper execution on a Windows machine.

[Ray Documentation](https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html)