# Construct a python function programmatically from given components

Tags: python, function, eval

I have a list of python functions, e.g.,

```
def f1(x, a): return x + a
def f2(x, y, a, b): return x * a + y * b
def f3(c, d, e): return c * d - e
def f4(y, z): return 2 * y - z
...
my_functions = [f1, f2, f3, f4 ...]
```

and I want to combine all pairs of them in a predefined way, e.g., by taking a product:

```
my_products = [product(f,g) for f,g in itertools.combinations(my_functions, 2)]
```

Thus `product` takes 2 functions, `f` and `g`, and produces a function that computes their product: `product(f1,f2)` should return

```
def f1_f2(x, a, y, b):
    return f1(x=x, a=a) * f2(x=x, y=y, a=a, b=b)
```

With Lisp I would have used a simple [macro](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/03_ababb.htm).

With Perl I would have created a string representation of `f1_f2` and used [`eval`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/eval).

What do I do with Python?
Write a file and load it?
Use [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec)?
[`eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval)?
[`compile`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile)?

**PS1**. The resulting functions will be passed to [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html), so all functions in question (especially the return value of `product`!) must take *positional* arguments rather than kw dicts.

The argument functions will have intersecting sets of argument names which have to be handled properly.

**PS2** If you think this is an [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) please suggest other approaches to generating function arguments for [`curve_fit`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

Comment: There's pretty much never a good reason to use `eval`.

Comment: If the variable names weren't special, this would be very easy. It's doable in Python as it is (without anything awful like `eval` or `exec`), but it's going to take some glue - you need to write introspection code or use a library that does it for you.

Comment: (Mind, I'm making some assumptions above about what "this" is -- I'm _assuming_ that you're constructing a function that takes arguments named identically to the union of both child functions and passing those arguments through wherever the names match, but you aren't exactly spelling that out explicitly).

Comment: ...it's also a bit more extra work if instead of accepting kwargs you want to generate something where the typechecker can understand its signature; you should be explicit if that's what you're asking.

Comment: if it acceptable to define `f1` as `def f1(x, a, **kwargs): return x + a`?

Comment: @JonSG: not really.

Comment: Too bad, that would make the answer relatively simple.

Comment: (As a _general_ "what's the Python equivalent?" answer, the `ast` module is the big-hammer general-purpose tool for things you'd use macros for in LISP; but it's unwieldy, and often overkill if the requirements can be made to permit something simpler; unfortunately, the requirements here are... difficult to get a handle on: you're _showing_ your desired calling convention, but not _explaining the intended logic_ behind it, so we're being asked to figure out two separate things: the metaprogramming -- which some of us have a handle on -- _and_ the logic you presumably have in your head).

Comment: but how do you know how a function should be called among all combinations?

Comment: @cards: `res.__name__ = "_".join(f.__name__ for f in components)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Under the assumption that all of your functions are reasonable simple, i.e. don't have default values and don't have positional-only arguments, this should work:

```
from inspect import signature, Signature

def product(f, g):
    f_sig = signature(f)
    g_sig = signature(g)
    combined = f_sig.parameters | g_sig.parameters
    f_g_sig = Signature(combined.values())

    def f_g(*args, **kwargs):
        bound = f_g_sig.bind(*args, **kwargs)
        f_res = f(**{name: bound.arguments[name] for name in f_sig.parameters.keys()})
        g_res = g(**{name: bound.arguments[name] for name in g_sig.parameters.keys()})
        return f_res * g_res

    f_g.__signature__ = f_g_sig
    return f_g
```

We construct a `Signature` object using a combined argument list from both functions, then use that to bind the incoming arguments. Should even work for mixed positional and keyword arguments. For this to correctly work with `curve_fit`, we also set the (barely documented) `__signature__` attribute.

Comment: nice, thank you! alas, the returned function [cannot be pickled](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12019961/850781). Is there way around?!

Comment: @sds Bind it to a global name, and make sure `__name__` and `__qualname__` of that function are correct. Otherwise not really, you will need to provide a custom object that constructs these functions on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest rewriting your function to accept any number of keyword arguments. Then you can simply pass any arbitrary list of keyword arguments to both functions without externally knowing their signatures:

```
def f1(**kwargs): return kwargs['x'] + kwargs['a']
def f2(**kwargs): return kwargs['x'] * kwargs['a'] + kwargs['y'] * kwargs['b']
def f3(**kwargs): return kwargs['c'] * kwargs['d'] - kwargs['e']
def f4(**kwargs): return 2 * kwargs['y'] - kwargs['z']

def product(f, g):
    def fun(**kwargs):
        return f(**kwargs) * g(**kwargs)
    return fun

foo = product(f1, f2)

print(foo(x = 1, y = 2, a = 3, b = 4, c = 5))
```

Comment: If the function requires certain arguments those should not be part of kwargs.

Comment: This is how I would approach the problem as well except I would do `def f1(x, a, **kwargs): return x + a`.

Comment: @JonSG I'd even say `def f1(x, a, **_): return x + a` to be more explicit about the "throw-away" nature of the kwargs.

Comment: @YevhenKuzmovych Sure that would be perfectly acceptable to me. I just used the `**kwargs` as that is the convention.

Answer (score 0):

For that you'll need to filter keyword arguments for each of the functions:

```
def product(f, g):
    def f_g(**kwargs):
        f_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in f.__code__.co_varnames}
        g_kwargs = {k: v for k, v in kwargs.items() if k in g.__code__.co_varnames}
        return f(**f_kwargs) * g(**g_kwargs)
    return f_g

my_products = [product(f,g) for f,g in itertools.combinations(my_functions, 2)]
```

Comment: `f_g` must take positional parameters

Comment: @sds, did you explicitly specify that in your question _[before this answer was created](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/77447024/1)_? It's not generally acceptable to edit a question in a way that invalidates preexisting answers.

Comment: @sds How do you know which positional parameters go where?

Comment: ... i.e. how do you decide on the `x, a, y, b` order in your example and not (say) `x, y, a, b`.

Comment: this is what the question is about!

Comment: I feel like we have an XY problem here.

Comment: If that is what the question is about, do you potentially just want to treat the parameters as having a global value rather than accept them?

Comment: @sds, ...until I read your comment above, I certainly didn't _know_ that "decid[ing] on `x,a,y,b` instead of `x,y,a,b`" was what this question was about. It would be helpful if you wrote the question to focus narrowly on the Python metaprogramming challenge (which is a worthy one!) without the assumptions that the reader will understand `curve_fit`'s constraints and infer details of your requirements therefrom.